# Writing regular text in LaTeX code in Wordpress

Tags: spacing

I am trying to write post some content in a Wordpress blog 
that is

```
$latex Y=\{(x_n)\in X :x_n=1  for at most finitely many n \}$
```

When I publish this I got no spaces between text. How to get space in between text?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Wordpress does not really use LaTeX, but something like MathJaX, which is the same syntax, but a different engine. I fear, your question is off-topic here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer..but jetpack is essential

Comment: Well, you will probably need something like `\text{your text here}`, but @ChristianHupfer is right.

Comment: @TeXnician.. you mean after i install mathjax

Comment: Jetpack is irrelevant here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer..i am sorry but can you help me from this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Wordpress, by which most people mean the Wordpress installation at wordpress.com, does use LaTeX, not MathJax. It's not directly obvious from [their documentation](https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/), but try things like `$latex \let\hello\hbox f \hello{ is }g$` and `$latex \hbox{\pdftexbanner}$` which do what you'd expect. The latter shows “This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian kpathsea version 6.2.1dev)”. Or you can read [the code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-latex/trunk) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jetpack for Wordpress](https://jetpack.com/support/beautiful-math-with-latex/) supports MathJax and loads `amsmath`, so use `\text`

```
$latex Y = \{ (x_n) \in X : x_n = 1 \text{ for at most finitely many } n \}$
```

to obtain plain text within math content. Alternatively, write only math content within your `latex` structures:

```
$latex Y = \{ (x_n) \in X : x_n = 1$ for at most finitely many $latex n \}$
```

However, this will intermix the LaTeX (image) rendering with your default blog font and not look as polished.

Comment: @werner..its not work

Comment: ..please help me

Comment: i am working since fromm 3 hours i did't get solution please please help me

Comment: ....thank you so much for your now its working tqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq

Comment: Jetpack does not use MathJax. They seem to be using server-side LaTeX installations and dvi2png.

Comment: I left a comment on the question pointing out that Wordpress (specifically, the [WP LaTeX](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-latex/) plugin by Automattic installed on Wordpress.com, matching  [this documentation](https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/)) indeed uses (“real”) LaTeX, and that Mathjax has nothing to do with it. Of course, there are other plugins for Wordpress (the software, not Wordpress.com) that have different kinds of LaTeX-like support, including MathJax, KaTeX, or whatever.